# How to search if a word contains a few words

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of emails, such as

```
name@aol.com
name@company.com
name@gmail.com
```

In the above, I'm trying to get a count that does not include 'free' domains.

Whilst my above example is trivial, and it would easier to count by company.com, this is not what I want.

The logic I'm hoping for is

If the content of a cell contains "aol" or "gmail" or "yahoo" or "icloud", then return FALSE. Everything else is TRUE

My effort works, but seems clunky. Is there a better way

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("gmail",C2)),FALSE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("icloud",C2)),FALSE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("yahoo",C2)),FALSE,IF(ISBLANK(C2),FALSE,TRUE)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For an email address in cell `A2` and a list of free domains in range `D2:D5` use the formula `=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND($E$2:$E$5,A2)))`, as in this example:

[image]

If you're on an Excel version other than Excel 365, array-enter the formula by hitting `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` instead of just `Enter` (See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-array-formulas-8ff8257a-b28e-4e81-b4f8-30f793412dfa)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-that-do-not-contain-many-strings) you may try the following:

```
=SUM(1-(MMULT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&{"aol";"gmail";"yahoo";"icloud"},A1:A3))),{1,1,1,1})>0))
```

Or:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A3)-SUM(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@"&{"aol";"gmail";"yahoo";"icloud"},A1:A3))))
```

In versions of Excel other than O365, you might want to use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead of `SUM()`.